# Kafka Streams custom header on producer

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

I have multiple events in a topic and I am trying to process in these steps:

1. Filter the events based on header value
2. Apply deserialiser
3. Group by key
4. Aggregate to produce a new KTable
5. New KTable will be streamed to the same topic as a new Event with a new header.

I am able to access the header using transformValues but not sure how to inject new header values when doing toStream.

```
streamsBuilder.stream("my-topic")
.transformValues(new Transformer())//access headers here n filter few events
.groupByKey(Serialized.with(Serdes.String(),null)
.aggregate(()->my avro object initialization,(key,value,aggregate)->newValue(Value,aggregate),Materialized.as("my-store").withKeySerde(Serdes.String()).withValueSerde(Serdes.ByteArray())
.mapValues((key,value)->convert to bytes).toStream()
```

NB: I am new to KStream.

Comment: You can do another `transform()` after `toStream()` to access and modify the headers before you write the result to the output topic.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Processor API](https://kafka.apache.org/22/documentation/streams/developer-guide/processor-api.html#accessing-processor-context) to add custom headers. Implement process method in the same way as you did to access headers.

```
new Processor() { 
    ......
   @override
   public void process(String key, String value) {
       // add a header to the elements
       context().headers().add.("key", "key");
   }
   ...
}
```

Comment: Not that `Header` objects/instances are shared over multiple operators (KS does not deep copy the objects, but passed references around). Hence, you need to write you code "carefully" and take side effects into account to get it right.